Raid data no longer showing up after disconnecting and reconnecting drives
I have WD Mybook Duo 16tb raid. I opened it up and took out the drives because I was originally planning on putting in some drives from a different WD mybook duo 16 tb raid that had malfunctioned due to me plugging it in with the wrong charger.
I decided against plugging in the other drives because I wasn't sure they would work in this other chassis without messing with stuff from this raid, and just decided to plug the old drives right back in where they came from. But now that I've plugged the raid back into my computer, my computer won't show the volume at all. It recognizes that it's got a raid plugged in but it says that it's "not initialized". I don't want to initialize it because this raid is the backup to my other raid that malfunctioned. I didn't think that merely unplugging the drives and putting them right back where they came from would cause this kind of issue. What do I do?
